# Updating gfortran without updating GCC

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

Is it possible to update `gfortran` without updating the GCC in a Linux operating system?

Comment: Depending on your linux distribution, you can have several versions of gcc and gfortran installed at the same time (typically called gcc-4.9, gfortran-5, etc). What do you mean exactly by "not updating GCC"?

Comment: @MarcGlisse  I do not want to make other programs use the new GCC. I want to keep using the current GCC but use a more recent gfortran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since `gfortran` is part of the GCC, just updating `gfortran` could be a little tricky. However, you can download the `gfortran` binaries, as well as the required `gcc-infrastructure` package from the [official site](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries).

You can unzip the two archives into a folder (e.g., `/usr/local/gfortran`) and start using this version of GCC (incl. `gfortran`) alongside the version provided by your GNU Linux system. It might be helpful to set up a short shell script to adjust the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to use this local version. The `gfortran` site [provides further details](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries64Linux) and examples on how to achieve that.

In essence, you need to do something like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/gfortran/bin:$PATH"
```

and

```
if [ -z "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/gfortran/lib"
else
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/gfortran/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
fi
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

provided that you installed the local version in `/usr/local/gfortran`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me references I could look that would help me do this? I am not sure how to do this and I am worried that I will overwrite something in the process.

Comment: Just extract the two archives (`gfortran` and `gcc-infrastructure`) in the same directory (e.g. `/usr/local/gfortran`). That's it :)

Comment: If you want/need to compile it, follow this: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC.  The trick is to change the following line (../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=/projects/tools/gcc-5.3.0 --enable-languages=fortran --disable-multilib).  That is from a recent install of mine.  Then do the path stuff as above to point to this folder.  Put that in .profile  I just did this and it worked.

Comment: PS, my comment above has disable multilib since my OS is 64 bit (and it wouldn't compile without that).