# Select two version of gcc on linux as non-administrators

Tags: linux, gcc, fortran

Here is my question.

1. The linux cluster which I can use(not a sudo-user) has installed `gcc 4.2.1`.

   ```
   >which gcc
   >/usr/bin/gcc
   ```
2. For some reason, I need a newer version of `gcc`. So, I have install `gcc 5.1.0` on `/disk3/lly/lib/gcc-5.1.0`(I can't install it in `/usr/bin` due to the limits of authority)
3. I still want the older version `gcc 4.2.1`, and sometimes I want to use `gcc 5.1.0`. So, I want to find a safe way switching them easily.

I have read some post, and summarized one simple method here:

```
## Overlay the older one
## Newer gcc at /disk3/lly/lib/gcc-5.1.0--> For simplification, take $NEW for insted
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm gcc
sudo ln -s $NEW/bin/gcc gcc 

## Change back to gcc 4.2.1    
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/gcc gcc
```

But I don't have enough permission, are there some alternative way to achieve my target?

Comment: Related: [Updating gfortran without updating GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178094/updating-gfortran-without-updating-gcc/36178285#36178285) and [GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /path_name/bin/gfortran)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193463/glibc-2-11-not-found-required-by-path-name-bin-gfortran).

Comment: Before posting new questions, please do your research.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After I solve my problem, I'll delete this one.

Comment: Although it somehow *is* a duplicate, it is a bit far-fetched IMHO that someone would look how to install gfortran if he has problems installing gcc

Comment: @tofro Notice the tag [tag:fortran]. gfortran is a part of GCC, it is one software package. It is not installing gfortran, it is installing GCC with the fortran part enabled. Read the description of tag [tag:gcc], it is not GNU C compiler, it is GNU compiler collection.

Comment: @Alexander Vogt. I have read about the question "Install gfortran in Linux as a user". The answer use `/users/home/myself/gcc-5.3.0/bin/gfortran Test.f90` to test one _f90_ file for one time. But I need to run an __.exe__ after an successfully compliation. Is it  practicable to use ` `/users/home/myself/gcc-5.3.0/bin/gfortran  xxx.exe`?

Comment: You don't run executable using a compiler! Also, `.exe` on linux does not mean anything, it is just a name.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: gcc is *built* against a hard-coded installation path. Just copying somewhere else will not make it work. You will need to re-compile gcc (and, possibly binutils and maybe even the matching libc if it's not the same as the installed version) from scratch.

Your main problem at the moment is that `$NEW/bin/gcc`is not in your `PATH`. once you add it like

> export PATH=${NEW}/bin/gcc:${PATH}

it will start your version of the compiler frontend, but you will soon run into a bunch of other problems that are not that easy to solve.

Comment: Sorry, this is not exactly true. You can have relative paths with GCC installation. And you probably **don't want to** re-build binutils! Additionally, you don't even touch the point of setting the library paths. The linked questions have answers that are much more detailed.

Comment: From the gcc configuration manual: "--prefix=dirname
Specify the toplevel installation directory. *This is the recommended way to install the tools into a directory other than the default*. The toplevel installation directory defaults to /usr/local." - Note I'm not saying you *can't* tweak a build into running in arbitrary places. But that seems to be beyond the capabilities of the OP.

Comment: This is just for convenient installation. There are many toolchains out there that you can download, extract locally and directly use. No tweaking involved.